# WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies and reflective information error

Tags: jboss, wildfly, ejb-3.2

```
17:15:41,160 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "ETS_EAR.ear"
```

was rolled back with the following failure message:

```
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ETS_EAR.ear\".\"ETSServices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"ETSServices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\" of deployment \"ETS_EAR.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for interface com.*.ets.remote.LoggingRemoteInter with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ETS_EAR.ear.ETSServiceRemote-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/*/ets/client/jsflogging/ParentLoggingTO
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xocialive.ets.client.jsflogging.ParentLoggingTO from [Module \"deployment.ETS_EAR.ear.ETSServiceRemote-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\" from Service Module Loader]",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ETS_EAR.ear\".\"ETSValidators-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"ETSValidators-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\" of deployment \"ETS_EAR.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.*.validators.MCSValidatorEJB with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ETS_EAR.ear.ETSValidators-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link */*/*/YEFIErrorStructure/xml/schemas/version2_3/CommonErrorStructure (Module \"deployment.ETS_EAR.ear.MCSIntegration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\" from Service Module Loader): org/apache/axis/AxisFault"
    },
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"ETS_EAR.ear\".WeldStartService",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"ETS_EAR.ear\".beanmanager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"ETS_EAR.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"ETS_EAR.ear\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"ETS_EAR.ear\".WeldStartService]"]
}
```

Comment: Did you check this? java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xocialive.ets.client.jsflogging.ParentLoggingTO

Answer (score 0):

Use @resource(lookup =...) instead of @resource(name

[Source](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel/issues/2546)